# Can I run use Docker API client inside a container?

Tags: python, api, docker

I have a python program which uses docker API client. Everything works fine if I run the python program in my laptop.However, it stops working if I run the python program inside a container.

I know it is kinda strange to do this way but is there a way I can use Docker API inside a container?

Comment: Are you trying to run docker inside a docker container?

Comment: no, the container will use the docker outside the container.

Comment: The point of containers is to create a separate computing environment from the host OS.  The "inside" of the container is therefore essentially ignorant of whatever is happening "outside" of the container.

Comment: In short "is there a way I can use Docker API inside a container?", the answer is no, not in the way you are thinking.  The way that you would accomplish this is essentially the same as the way that you would control the docker on one machine from another machine on the same network.

Comment: [remote docker control](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can volume mount /var/run/docker.sock into my container and my container inside can talk to the docker outside.